# Can I add an MFD to my VW Polo?

Tags: electrical, vw

I have a 2004 Polo 9N, very basic (even has wind-up windows!) and was wondering if I could retrofit the MFD that the higher-spec models have?

Thanks,

Gareth

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What do you want to display

Comment: Mainly the speed, temperature, MPG and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. However, it would probably be more trouble than it is worth.

If this was an option for your car, you just need to obtain all the related parts and install them. This would be at least the MFD and related wiring. Maybe the ECU, more wiring harnesses,  sensors, etc. would be needed.

If it wasn't an option for *your* car, then quite a bit of DIY wiring would be involved.

Either way I doubt it would be easy.

Comment: Might even be easier to either go aftermarket or even roll your own.